# How are we supposed to use tags associated with a person?

Tags: support, asking-questions, tags

The description for the "donald-trump" tag is:

> for questions where the claim is about Donald Trump. Do not use this tag for questions about stuff Trump claims.

When I posted the question [Did a large number of celebrities threaten to go on strike until Trump resigns?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36704/did-a-large-number-of-celebrities-threaten-to-go-on-strike-until-trump-resigns), I didn't use the tag, since the question is about a supposed protest against Mr. Trump, not a claim against him. Now, that tag has been added. Is this an appropriate addition?

Comment: I hesitate to steal ideas from Shog9 (that's his prerogative :) but... in a large scheme of things, whether that tag is or isn't present on one question seems like *a matter not really worth caring all that much*, about independently of whether you agree or disagree with intended tag usage. (not to denigrate your specific question, i'm just worried that Skeptics is on a glide path to SciFi.SE level tag wars, which waste everyone's time without much of a site improvement). In the words of management speak, **Impact Effort Matrix** matters.

Answer (score 4):

Trump is the *object* of the claim, in other words what the claim is about, and this means that the tag is appropriate.

If Trump were the *subject* of the claim, in other words the *claimant*, then the tag should not be used.

- Trump said that the Earth is flat (DO NOT USE)
- Is trump a reptilian? (USE)
- Trump said he is a reptilian, is it true? (USE)

Compare with biology:

- if a claim is about biology, it gets the tag
- if a claim is made by a biologist, but it's not about biology, it does not.

Comment: What if a biologist makes a claim that Trump is a reptilian?